# Configure OpenVPN with many users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, tc

Similar to this question I am looking at connecting 1000's of concurrent users:

[OpenVPN performance: how many concurrent clients are possible?](https://serverfault.com/questions/439848/openvpn-performance-how-many-concurrent-clients-are-possible)

To save CPU cycles I would like to know if there is another solution outside of OpenVPN to bandwidth shape this many concurrent users?

Comment: I hope to disable your encryption you dont put your job at risk. For stolen data heads got chopped pretty fast.

Comment: @yagmoth555 OpenVPN can be used for more than just security - whoever is down voting this question needs to think outside of the security box :)

Comment: I will glady upvote if you give me more detail on the use :) as for me a vpn it's to connect from the external to the internal, and having non encrypted channel is a risk for a 'man-in-the-middle' attack

Comment: I vote this up, as I can think of possible uses, for example it can be used in an internal network, as a cheap way for certain network scenarios, as shown in http://superuser.com/a/1072188/299628 where no encryption is required.

Comment: @rda I have accepted your answer below - yes, OpenVPN can be used in many scenarios for companies that are outside of just security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284024/60293) an approach is shown to let OpenVPN run with **multiple instances** for better performance.

As mentioned in [this forum](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?p=7923#p7923) post, OpenVPN could run into performance problems when the client count per instance exceeds 200 users, this is because of the monolithic way it was coded in. This will not change until version 3 as stated in the post.

Answer (score 1):

From a performance perspective (OpenVPN offers more than just encryption), this is key

After further research, yes you can disable encryption in OpenVPN with these configuration directives:

> auth none
>
> cipher none

Set these in your server configuration and you will have no security at all provided by OpenVPN

See for example: http://docs.openvpn.net/under-the-hood/change-encryption-cipher-in-access-server/